# How to append QFile to QList<QFile>

Tags: qt

I am creating a post form-data request with 10 to 15 images in them. to minimize the code, I am using QList in order to store the location of the images

Ihave tried changing *QList  * files = new QList* to *QList files* but i am getting an error

```
 C:\Qt_Projects\SecretaryApp\handler.cpp:130: error: no matching function for call to 'QList<QFile>::append(QFile*&)'
     files.append((tempfile));
                             ^
```

Here is the code inside the function

```
QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
multiPart->setBoundary("----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");


QList<QFile>  * files = new QList<QFile>;
QList<QHttpPart> fileparts;


for(int i=0;i<urls.length();i++)
{
    QFile * tempfile = new QFile(urls[i].toLocalFile());

    tempfile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    qDebug()<<urls[i].toLocalFile();

    files->append((tempfile));  <------error here
}


for(int i=0;i<urls.length();i++)
{
        QHttpPart filePart;
        filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,QVariant("form-data; name=\"uploadImage\"; filename="+files[i]->fileName()));
        filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/jpg"));   // file type header MIME type
        filePart.setBodyDevice(files[i]);

        fileparts.append(filePart);
}


for(int i=0;i<urls.length();i++)
        files[i].setParent(multiPart);

for(int i=0;i<urls.length();i++)
        multiPart->append(fileparts[i]);

QNetworkRequest request((QUrl(sendImageAPI)));
```

How do i fix this error. Is this possible ? or should i be better off using vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
QList<QFile>  * files = new QList<QFile>;
```

to

```
QList<QFile * >  files;
```

or if you need your list on heap:

```
QList<QFile *>  * files = new QList<QFile *>;
```

because you use `QFile *` <- pointers

Comment: so correct me if im wrong, it seems that i have created a pointers to the QList instead of the QFile right?

Comment: @Jack, yes, your list is a "pointer" of QFile objects, but you are trying to append pointers of QFile objects to your list...

Comment: I see Thank you very much for pointing out what i have missed

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Xplatforms answer, I would add that you should be careful with object ownership always that you use new. I'd prefer to use:

```
QList<QFile *>  files
```

if you can. Or you may have a memory leak if you don't manually call delete after. The QFiles are ok since you are transferring ownership by calling setParent (supposing that multiPart is properly deleted).